# Sum total of a column SQL Percentage

Tags: sql, oracle, join, percentage

I'm trying to get the final record as total of the count and percentage:

```
    SELECT  region,  count(*) as total, concat(to_char(round(count(*) * 100/ sum(count(*)) over() ,2),'990.99'),
'%') perc
FROM (SELECT 
    CASE
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) >= 'A' 
                      AND Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) <= 'C' THEN 'America' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) >= 'J' 
                      AND Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) <= 'R' THEN 'Poland' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) >= 'S' 
                      AND Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) <= 'Z' THEN 'Euro' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 'North Africa' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) BETWEEN 6 AND 7 THEN 'Australia' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) BETWEEN 8 AND 9 THEN 'China' 
                 ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
               END AS region 
        FROM   vehicle) s 
GROUP  BY region 
UNION 
SELECT 'Total' Region, 
       Count(*) TOTAL, 
       concat(to_char(count(*) * 100/ sum(count(*)) over(),'990.99'),
'%') perc       
FROM vehicle ;
```

I get this:

```
        Region        TOTAL   PERC
         America       66     31.28%
         Poland        89     42.18%
         Europe         1     .47%
       Australia       1      .47%
         China        54      25.59%
          Total          211    100.00%
```

Expected is :

```
    Region        TOTAL   PERC
     America       66     31.28%
     Poland        89     42.18%
     Europe         1     0.47%
   Australia       1      0.47%
     China        54      25.59%
   Total          211    99.99%
```

I'm trying to get the 99.99 value as total that is the sum of the perc column how do i do that?

Comment: Why do you want 99.99 instead of 100.00%?

Comment: It makes no sense trying to actually compute the total percentage. You know it is 100% already, so why not just use a literal value?

Comment: `count(*) * 100/ sum(count(*)) over()` returns an `int`, so the round you do has no effect, try with `round(count(*) * 100.0/ sum(count(*)) over() ,2)` (notice 100.0), was that your problem ?

Comment: That's the requirement Im looking for! @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @nfgl No I edited my question I'm getting 100.00 where in I need 99.99 which is the sum of Perc column.

Comment: That's the requirement Im looking for! @GMB

Comment: You could use the ROLLUP function to get the last row with total instead of doing a UNION to get the total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This meets the requirement

```
with regions as (
SELECT  region,  count(*) as total, round(count(*) * 100/ sum(count(*)) over(),2) perc
FROM (SELECT 
    CASE
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) >= 'A' 
                      AND Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) <= 'C' THEN 'America' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) >= 'J' 
                      AND Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) <= 'R' THEN 'Poland' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) >= 'S' 
                      AND Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) <= 'Z' THEN 'Euro' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 'North Africa' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) BETWEEN 6 AND 7 THEN 'Australia' 
                 WHEN Substr(veh_vin, 1, 1) BETWEEN 8 AND 9 THEN 'China' 
                 ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
               END AS region 
        FROM   vehicle) s 
GROUP  BY region )
select region, total, concat(to_char(perc,'990.99'), '%') perc from regions
union all
select 'Total' region, sum(Total) total, concat(to_char(sum(Perc),'990.99'), '%') perc
from regions
```